# how to start remote host weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I create a weblogic cluster system on different hosts(10.0.0.192 and 10.0.0.32). When I try to start weblogic server at 10.0.0.32 from 10.0.0.192 admin console, It just stucks. From "summary of servers" it says "STARTING      TASK IN PROGRESS(9 minutes)".

By the way both weblogic server's node manager status are "Reachable".

Here is log file(from 10.0.0.32)

```
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:02 PM EET> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify  -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:02 PM EET> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:02 PM EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000395> <The following extensions directory contents added to the end of the classpath: 
C:\Oracle\Middleware_12.1.1.0\user_projects\domains\base_domain\lib\sipactivator.jar.> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:02 PM EET> <Info> <Server> <BEA-002647> <The service plug-in, com.oracle.core.sip.activator, was added from C:\Oracle\Middleware_12.1.1.0\user_projects\domains\base_domain\lib\sipactivator.jar.> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:02 PM EET> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 20.14-b01 from Sun Microsystems Inc..> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:24 PM EET> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13340309 Thu Feb 16 18:30:21 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13019800 Mon Jan 16 16:53:54 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13391585 Thu Feb 02 10:18:36 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13516712 Mon Jan 30 15:09:33 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13641115 Tue Jan 31 11:19:13 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13603813 Wed Feb 15 19:34:13 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13424251 Mon Jan 30 14:32:34 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13361720 Mon Jan 30 15:24:05 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13421471 Wed Feb 01 11:24:18 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13657792 Thu Feb 23 12:57:33 IST 2012
WebLogic Server 12.1.1.0  Wed Dec 7 08:40:57 PST 2011 1445491 > 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:46 PM EET> <Emergency> <Management> <BEA-141151> <The Administration Server could not be reached at http://192.168.145.1:7001.> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:46 PM EET> <Info> <Configuration Management> <BEA-150018> <This server is being started in Managed Server independence mode in the absence of the Administration Server.> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:46 PM EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:46 PM EET> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool.> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:46 PM EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Oracle\Middleware_12.1.1.0\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\10-0-0-32-server\logs\10-0-0-32-server.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms, such as Windows.> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:46 PM EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Oracle\Middleware_12.1.1.0\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\10-0-0-32-server\logs\10-0-0-32-server.log00004. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Oracle\Middleware_12.1.1.0\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\10-0-0-32-server\logs\10-0-0-32-server.log.> 
<Dec 16, 2013 2:12:46 PM EET> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\Oracle\Middleware_12.1.1.0\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\10-0-0-32-server\logs\10-0-0-32-server.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.>
```

Comment: There's this 192.168.145.1 IP address in your log, what does it correspond to?

Comment: @foch Nothing I think it is default. I didn't give any IP address like that.

Comment: I'm not a network expert, but here it seems that there is a mix between class A and class C private IP addresses... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network You should configure everything to work with Class C instead.

Comment: Make sure your `listen-address` is configured properly for each server and the `ADMIN_URL` is correct in your startManagedWebLogic.cmd file.

Answer (score 0):

i see below error

http://192.168.145.1:7001.>

This main causes of this error are

1. Admin server is down or unavailable or not pingable
2. The admin port is not opened or not enabled in firewall

you are  trying to access the admin server with http port....generally we reach admin with https port...

Please check these solutions..let me know if you need anything